# show message in log file with php

Tags: java, php, logging, tcl

I need to know how to show a message in the log in apache with php, I know that java has this instruction

> System.out.println

and in `tcl`

```
 ns_log notice
```

but there are some equivalent in php?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Technically, that's a feature of a Tcl application (that was originally called “naviserver” long ago, hence the prefix).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the syslog function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.syslog.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use [error_log](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) to output directly to the error log.

Answer (score 1):

Use error_log() function to set custom error messages

```
error_log("Oracle database not available!", 0);
```

Or you can save the errors to custom log file as

```
error_log("Oops, something went wrong!", 3, "/var/tmp/my-errors.log");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the level of logging on your PHP.ini, to debug or warming. Then use error_log or syslog to print to php_error.log or what ever u configure ur logging file is.